# PHP failed to set HTTP header when generating bar code image

Tags: php, http-headers, barcode

I am using the composer package [Piceq\Barcode](https://github.com/picqer/php-barcode-generator) to generate the bar code image. I just start using it by the simple testing code:

```
$barCode = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$barCode = $barCode->getBarcode($inputs['code'], $barCode::TYPE_CODE_128);

ob_clean();
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $barCode;
```

The content of `$barCode` looks something like the binary content of the generated image. The problem is that it is sent to the browser as text/html. What have I missed so that the HTTP header is not set correctly?

Comment: My thoughts are the headers are being sent by whitespace prematurely. Not sure you ned that `ob_clean();` mind you

Comment: No, I have tried removing the space in the header, but still not setting the header correctly. The ob_clean() is needed based on my previous experience in generating image, but you are right that sometimes it is not needed. Just added to make sure it is not that extra content make the header not set.

Comment: On the other hand, I have another function generating QR code, which has space in declaring header. So it is unlikely to be the space.

Comment: I've checked and the example works good for me. I think the previous headers already is sent to client, so you can't change content type.  ob_clean can't help in this case.

Comment: _“No, I have tried removing the space in the header”_ - that’s not what they meant, they meant whether you might have created output (even if it was “just” whitespace) anywhere before that. Do you have proper PHP error reporting enabled, so that PHP could warn you if you tried to issue a header after output has already started?

Comment: there is no problem when i execute your code in my machine ..check $inputs['code']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what's the reason ,but the problem turns out to be the `echo` that caused the problem. Changing the `echo` to `die()` solves the problem.

Here is the working code.

```
$barCode = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorPNG();
$barCode = $barCode->getBarcode($inputs['code'], $barCode::TYPE_CODE_128);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
die($barCode);
```